# Is Ubuntu desktop 32 bit source code the same as Ubuntu desktop 64 bit source code

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

Is Ubuntu desktop 32 bit source code the same as Ubuntu desktop 64 bit source code?

I recently had occasion to go backwards from 64 bit to 32 bit and they seems subtlety different.

Answer (score 1):

The source code of 64 bit OS will only differ to support the 64 bit architecture and any extra features required by it. Everything else(including the GUI) should essentially be the same.

These changes are back-end changes and will not be visible to you in the GUI. The only difference they make is in performance and RAM usage.

The reasons why you find changes are probably

- You are looking at two different versions of Ubuntu
- You are looking at systems which are configured differently and have different set and/or different versions of softwares.